# Developer Exception Page is blank if added to IApplicationBuilder after MVC

Tags: c#, exception, asp.net-core

Developer Exception Page (`app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage()`) is blank if added to `IApplicationBuilder` after MVC (`app.UseMvc()`) in `Startup.cs` `Configure` method.

[image: Developer Exception Page added after MVC]

Developer Exception Page works fine if added before MVC.

[image]

[image]

Is this behavior intentional or am doing something wrong?

- Visual Studio Code 0.10.6 on Mac
- Microsoft.AspNet.Diagnostics 1.0.0-rc1-final
- Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc 6.0.0-rc1-final
- DNX Mono 1.0.0-rc1-update1

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The behavior you're seeing is **TOTALLY intentional**: in ASP.NET 5, middleware are executed in the same order as they are registered.

When registering the developer exception page middleware after MVC, it has no chance to catch the exception thrown by your controller action (as it's not even invoked). The exception is thus intercepted by the server (Kestrel), that returns a 500 response, and that's why you see a "blank page".

Answer (score 6):

Even though you got an answer to this, I want to post an explanation about why adding the exception middleware doesn't catch anything added before it.

So, you have a pipeline that you build with middleware. Each middleware will (usually) invoke the one added after it. So you have something like:

`M1 -> M2 -> M3 -> M4 -> ... -> Mn`

When a request comes in, it will go to `M1` which can do the following:

1. Pass it further.
2. Stop.

If it passes further, then the middleware will have another chance to handle the request when it comes back. So the request goes like this:

```
Request | M1 | M2 | M3 | ... | Mn
--------+----+----+----+-----+---
    X   |    |    |    |     |   
       -->   |    |    |     |   
        |  X |    |    |     |   
        |   -->   |    |     |   
        |    |  X |    |     |   
        |    |   -->   |     |   
        |    |    |  X |     |   
        |    |    |   -->    |   
        |    |    |    |    --> X 
        |    |    |    |    <--
        |    |    |   <--    |       
        |    |    |  X |     |       
        |    |   <--   |     |             
        |    |  X |    |     |       
        |   <--   |    |     |       
        |  X |    |    |     |       
       <--   |    |    |     |
    X   |    |    |    |     |
```

Each middleware is a method call:

```
M1() 
   // Do something before M2
   M2()
       // Do something before M3
       M3()
           ...
       // Do something after M3
   // Do something after M2
```

So, if anything happens in a middleware, any middleware in front of it has the chance to react to that. Anything after, doesn't know about it. E.g. If `M2` throws an exception, `M1` can catch it because `M2` runs in the context of `M1` but `M3` either was not invoked yet or has already completed.