# using UseGoogleAuthentication

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, google-oauth, .net-core

I am trying to build an application with google as the identity provider in asp.net core.

I used the bootstrap web application initialized by the dotnet cli tool:

```
dotnet new --type web
```

I added the `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Google` nuget in my project.json.

I created a google application and a clientid/secret and added the google middle ware:

```
app.UseGoogleAuthentication(new GoogleOptions{
                ClientId = "<clientId>",
                ClientSecret = "<clientSecret>"
            });
```

But then, following the tutorial here, the following line should return a loginProvider collection with one element:

```
SignInManager.GetExternalAuthenticationSchemes()
```

But all I get is an empty IEnumerable. I tried to follow the source code but failed to find what I am doing wrong (bad client id configuration, missed something in Startup Configure(Service) functions).

How to get `SignInManager.GetExternalAuthenticationSchemes()` to return the google loginProvider?

Comment: Strange, it has nothing to do with Ids, it won't validate even if we put some value there. You're using the same code as generated by dotnet new right? I did the same and working without any issue

Comment: Thanks. I finally figured it out. See my answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After some tests I figured it out. My mistake was to use `UseGoogleAuthentication` after `UseMvc`. Moving it just before fixes my issue.

I guess this posts explains it:

[Developer Exception Page is blank if added to IApplicationBuilder after MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34560596/developer-exception-page-is-blank-if-added-to-iapplicationbuilder-after-mvc)

Comment: I thought this issue was a systemic bug in Core when testing VS2017 RC2! What a simple solution. I moved my app.UseFacebookAuthentication(... middleware code above my app.UseMvc(routes =>... code and it works perfectly, Thanks!